# AWS Route 53 pointing me back to EC2 Public IPv4 Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

I recently changed my GoDaddy Nameservers from Hostgator to AWS Route 53,
Works well and all, but I noticed that when I get redirected to the website by using `mydomain.com`, though I can access the website, It changes the `mydomain.com` to my EC2 instance Public IPv4 address.

Here's how I set up my hosted zone in Route 53 :

```
|     Record Name  |   Type   |   Alias   | Value/Route traffic to     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   mydomain.com   |    A     |    Yes    |    www.mydomain.com        |
|   mydomain.com   |    NS    |    No     |    4 NS Records here       |
|   mydomain.com   |    SOA   |    No     |    some records here       |
| www.mydomain.com |    A     |    No     |    EC2 Public IPv4 address |
```

I've tried changing the `Type` of Record name with `Alias` marked as `Yes` into `CNAME`, but It didn't work. I also set the Security group of my ec2 instance to `HTTP->Anywhere` and `HTTPS->Anywhere` as per instruction. But still no luck.

Here's how the problems looks like:

```
Types `mydomain.com` to the browser -> gets redirected to the website -> URL becomes an IP address.
```

Any idea guys?

Comment: If there is a redirect happening it will be somewhere in the application, Route 53 handles DNS resolution but does not perform redirects.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the hosted zone configuration table. Are you possibly using WordPress on the EC2? Then maybe you have this issue - https://serverpilot.io/docs/solution-to-wordpress-showing-ip-address-instead-of-domain/#:~:text=If%20you%20installed%20WordPress%20using,General%20Settings%2C%20as%20shown%20below.

Comment: @MilanG Gee!, really, thanks dude!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to @MilanG.

The Hosted zone configurations were all good. The problem is within Wordpress configurations.
Normally one would install wordpress directly from hosting server or locally.In my case, I installed the wordpress on the ec2 instance server that's why its pointing me back to the public ip address.

To fix the issue:

1. Go to **wordpress dashboard**
2. **Settings** > **General Settings**
3. Locate **WordPress Address(URL)** and **Site Address(URL)** and edit their respective values with **mydomain.com**

Refer [here](https://serverpilot.io/docs/solution-to-wordpress-showing-ip-address-instead-of-domain/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20installed%20WordPress%20using,General%20Settings%2C%20as%20shown%20below) for clear explanation.